# Upper bound on the expected value of the norm of a gaussian vector

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution, random-matrices

I'm trying to prove the following:

Let X be a fixed matrix of dimension $d*n$ and let $g$ be a standard gaussian vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Then: $\mathbb{E} \||Xg\|| \leq \operatorname{Tr}\left(\left[X X^T\right]^{1/2}\right)$.

This is taken from https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.05200.pdf (proof of Lemma 5.3).
By taking the power and the square root of the norm inside of the expected value, writing the squared norm in terms of trace, and using Jensen's inequality with the square root I managed to prove that $\mathbb{E} \||Xg\|| \leq \sqrt{\operatorname{Tr}\left(X X^T\right)}$.

How can I prove, instead the result with the square root inside of the argument of the trace? I'm having some troubles.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see where the author uses that fact in the proof. In his final lines he says
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{E}_{\tilde{X}}\left[\sup _{v, w \in B} Z_{v, w}\right] \leq \mathbf{E}_{\tilde{X}}\left[\sup _{v, w \in B} Y_{v, w}\right] & \leq\|\tilde{X}\| \mathbf{E}\left\|\Sigma^{1 / 2} g\right\|+\|\Sigma\|^{1 / 2} \mathbf{E}_{\tilde{X}}\|\tilde{X} g\| \\
& \leq\|\tilde{X}\| \sqrt{\operatorname{Tr}[\Sigma]}+\|\Sigma\|^{1 / 2} \operatorname{Tr}\left[\tilde{X} \tilde{X}^*\right]^{1 / 2}
\end{aligned}
$$
by the Slepian-Fernique inequality. Taking the expectation with respect to $\tilde{X}$ and using that $\mathbf{E}\|\tilde{X}\|=\mathbf{E}\|X\|$ and $\mathbf{E}\left[\operatorname{Tr}\left[\tilde{X} \tilde{X}^*\right]^{1 / 2}\right] \leq \sqrt{n \operatorname{Tr}[\Sigma]}$ yields the conclusion.

And the conclusion he wishes to establish is with $r(\Sigma):=\operatorname{Tr}[\Sigma] /\|\Sigma\|$
$$
\mathbf{E}\|Z-\Sigma\| \lesssim \mathbf{E}\|X\| \frac{\sqrt{\operatorname{Tr}[\Sigma]}}{n}+\|\Sigma\| \sqrt{\frac{r(\Sigma)}{n}}
$$
where
$$
\mathbf{E}\|Z-\Sigma\| \leq \frac{2}{n} \mathbf{E}\left[\sup _{v, w \in B} Z_{v, w}\right].
$$
So all that needs to happen is that he takes the expectation of the list line of the first expression, and $\mathbf{E}\left[\operatorname{Tr}\left[\tilde{X} \tilde{X}^*\right]^{1 / 2}\right] \leq \sqrt{n \operatorname{Tr}[\Sigma]}$ indeed follows from Jensen's.

Comment: By $\operatorname{Tr} \left[ X X^T \right]^{1/2}$, you mean that the argument of the trace is to the power of 1/2 or that the whole trace is to the power of 1/2?
Because also the last step from Jensen, to me is clear in this terms:

Comment: $\mathbb{E}\left[\sqrt{\operatorname{Tr}\left(\tilde{X} \tilde{X}^T\right)} \right] \leq \sqrt{\mathbb{E}\left[\operatorname{Tr}\left(\tilde{X} \tilde{X}^T\right) \right]} =  \sqrt{\operatorname{Tr} \left(\mathbb{E}\left[\tilde{X} \tilde{X}^T \right]\right)} = \sqrt{\operatorname{Tr}\left(n \cdot \Sigma \right)} = \sqrt{n \cdot \operatorname{Tr}\left( \Sigma \right)}$. 
But not if the argument of the trace is to the 1/2 instead of the whole trace. 
Thanks for answering!

Comment: Yes I think the author intends the bottom one.

Comment: Ok, cool that's what I thought but the fact that he used a different notation for the same quantity on the two elements of the sum as the upper bound was making me doubt of my calculations. Thanks

Comment: No worries! Help a brother out to some meaningless internet points by hitting the check mark button. That way too no one else looks in to make sure the question needs an answer.